# Cannot start TomEE on Windows?

Tags: jakarta-ee, installation, ejb, openejb

This is the cmd output...

```
----------------------------------------------------------------

Installing the service 'TomEE' ...
Using CATALINA_HOME:    "C:\tomee"
Using CATALINA_BASE:    "C:\tomee"
Using JAVA_HOME:        "C:\program files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26"
Using JRE_HOME:         "C:\program files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre"
Using JVM:              "C:\program files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\server\jvm.dl
l"
""C:\tomee\bin\TomEE.x86.exe"" //IS//TomEE
[2013-04-09 16:16:39] [error] Unrecognized cmd option C:\tomee\bin\TomEE.x86.exe

[2013-04-09 16:16:39] [error] The specified module could not be found.
[2013-04-09 16:16:39] [error] Invalid command line arguments
[2013-04-09 16:16:39] [error] The specified module could not be found.
[2013-04-09 16:16:39] [error] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 1 (
Failed to parse command line arguments)
[2013-04-09 16:16:39] [error] The specified module could not be found.
Failed installing 'TomEE' service

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I did not configure any of the files. But Startup.bat works and expose localhost:8080. But when I tried to open Tomee Gui from the webpage. It didn't load.

Comment: C:\tomee\bin\TomEE.x86.exe is there in the bin folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just configured my TomEE v1.6.0 as a Windows service doing as follows:

1 - Run Windows CMD as an Administrator

2 - Go to TomEE bin folder (${tomee}\bin)

3 - Execute this command:

```
service.bat install
```

4 - Now just run your TomEE and test it

Hope this helps